# Running clion IDE from an Icon

Tags: linux

I downloaded clion IDE , but I can't see it as an Icon , I have to run it through the terminal , how can I setup it and run it from an icon ? also if I searched into the start menu I can't find it

Answer (score 1):

Just use snap package, see https://snapcraft.io/clion. If you don't want to, then you can get `clion.desktop` and `clion.png` (icon) from the snap and use it for your manually installed CLion.

```
curl -s https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/package/clion | jq -r '.download_url'
https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/download/6JBjLwyVchga4cOSDqhWJd9NgQfrTYam_145.snap

sudo mount 6JBjLwyVchga4cOSDqhWJd9NgQfrTYam_145.snap /mnt -t squashfs -o loop

mkdir ${HOME}/.icons
mkdir -p ${HOME}/.local/share/applications
cp /mnt/bin/clion.png $HOME/.icons/clion.png
CLION_SH=<path to clion.sh>
sed -e 's,^\(Icon=\).*,\1'"${HOME}"'/.icons/clion.png,' \
    -e 's,^\(Exec=\).*,\1'"${CLION_SH}"' %f,' \
    /mnt/snap/gui/clion.desktop > ${HOME}/.local/share/applications/clion.desktop
sudo umount /mnt
rm 6JBjLwyVchga4cOSDqhWJd9NgQfrTYam_145.snap
```